# flask env config.py don t find database : unable to get repr for class 'flask_sqlalcwmy.SQLAlchemy'

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I create a flask app with a postures db in cloud with .env file. when I run server, it seems it does not find database.
**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config

def init_app():
    """Construct core Flask application with embedded Dash app."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config())
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    with app.app_context():
        # Import parts of our core Flask app
        from . import routes
```

config.py:

```
import os
from dotenv import dotenv_values

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

configuration = dotenv_values(".env")

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

after step by step debug: for app, I have a app.config like this:

```
<Config {'ENV': 'development', 'DEBUG': False, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 'SECRET_KEY': 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed', 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200), 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS': True, 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093, 'CSRF_ENABLED': True, 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'DATABASE_URL=postgres://mqyl:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@queenie.db.XXXXXX.com:5432/rulXXXX', 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_NATIVE_UNICODE': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_ECHO': False, 'SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN': False, 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': None, 'SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS': {}}>
```

WSGI.py:

```
from application import init_app

app = init_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

trace error:

no trace only on debug mode value of db = SQLAlchemy(app) is
db: Unable to get repr for class flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy

Comment: `'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'DATABASE_URL=postgres://mqyl:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@queenie.db.XXXXXX.com:5432/rulXXXX'` - I don't think the URI should be prefixed with `"DATABASE_URL="`?

Comment: yes thanks. but it is still not working...SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI begins now by Postgres:

Comment: I tried to use psycopg2 and I m able to connect to db. but SQLACHEMY is not connecting...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: no trace but no db for sqlalchemy...

Answer (score 0):

find the solution...
DATABASE_URL=postgres:// is deprecate
I should use DATABASE_URL=**postgresql**://